# Can't register a new global variable inside a function

Tags: php, scope, php-8

I want my script to declare new variables while, at the same time, assign them and their value to an object. I therefore wanted to write a function to do this, but I can't get the function to declare the new variable in the outside scope.

I've tried an anonymous function and a normal one, and tried both combinations of setting the variable via the global keyword and the superglobal variable.

```
<?
    $output = [];
    
    // anonymous functions approach
    $addResult = function (string $key, float $value) use (&$output) {
        // 'global' approach
        global $$key;
        $$key = $value;
        
        // '$GLOBALS' approach
        $GLOBALS[$key] = $value;
        
        // rest of the function body (adding KV to obj)
        $output[$key] = $value;
    };
    
    // normal functions approach
    function addResult (string $key, float $value) {
        // 'global' approach
        global $$key;
        $$key = $value;
        
        // '$GLOBALS' approach
        $GLOBALS[$key] = $value;
        
        // rest of the function body (adding KV to obj)
        global $output;
        $output[$key] = $value;
    }
    
    // anonymous functions approach
    $addResult('var1', 4);
    echo $var1; // -> undefined
    
    // normal functions approach
    addResult('var1', 4);
    echo $var1; // -> undefined
?>
```

(For my tests I obviously always only commented in one pair of arrangements)

The code runs without *errors*, but shows the `Warning: Undefined variable $var1 in [path to file]`

Additionally, if possible, I would have the function definition in file `A` and the call to `addResult` in an included file `B`.

I am running php 8.0.25 on XAMPP on Win11, but the code must be compatible with the production server running php 8.0 on apache2 on debian.

UPDATE:

It appears the code works as expected when executed directly, but stops working when called from inside a included file. (I moved both the function definition and the call to the included file). Having the function definition in the topmost file is not desired.

Comment: The 'GLOBALS' approach should work, if I'm not mistaken.
But let's start with the basics: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Regarding 'define in A and call in B, which is included by A'...that's not a very good idea. Generally, you should include the file defining the function instead of including the file using the function included in the file.

It should work, mind you. But you may want to use `function_exists` prior to calling functions which may not exist.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium no error per se - just the warning that the variable is not defined.
I added this info to the queston body. thanks

Comment: Ah, I think I see the issue. Try running the example and let it echo the contents of the variable. You'll see it'll work. ;P

Comment: @RefugnicEternium about the includes: my current setup has some general logic in file A which then dynamically includes on of many file Bs, each with their own different businesslogic.

Comment: How does 'A' know which 'B' to include though?
I believe it'd be better to have a 'C' which determines (and includes) the correct 'B', which, in turn, includes the 'A'.

Comment: not so sound rude, but I don't see how that's relevant. The B Filename gets passed as a route parameter and checked against a switch of hardcoded values if you must know. Like so:
www.domain.com/path/data -> loads A
www.domain.com/paht/data/averages -> loads A, then B
www.domain.com/path/data/peaks -> loads A, then a different B
www.domain.com/path/data/../../.../var/... -> loads A

Comment: I was merely giving my two cents regarding file structures. You are free to do whatever you want and if it works for you: Fine.
On a slightly related note, did my answer help you resolve your issue?

Comment: well yes and no. It kind of said "it's not possible". Did you answer my question? yes. Did you solve my problem? no.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is, that your static analyzer doesn't 'see' the definition of the variable and thus marks it as 'not there'.

You could be including the file in a function, making all variables scoped inside that function.

To shut up the static analyzer (and to protect yourself against said error scenario), you'd need to access $GLOBALS outside the function as well.

Because in PHP you can never be entirely sure whether you're actually in the global namespace.

Tested with PHP 8.1.0 with Ubuntu 22

```
$output = [];

// anonymous functions approach
$addResult = function (string $key, float $value) use (&$output) {
    $output[$key] = $GLOBALS[$key] = $value;
};

// normal functions approach
function addResult (string $key, float $value) {
    $GLOBALS['output'][$key] = $GLOBALS[$key] = $value;
}

// anonymous functions approach
$addResult('var1', 8);
echo $var1;

// normal functions approach
addResult('var1', 4);
echo $var1;
```

Output: 84 (as expected).

Comment: I can't really accept that answer. The point of this was to have slick(ish) code, I absolutely do not want to use $GLOBALS throughout the script. To clearify: I would need to call said function ~50 Times

Comment: You are, of course, free to just ignore the warning and it should work just fine too. It is a warning of the static analyzer. Not an error. PHP should do as asked.

Comment: Actually no, I can't: If I echo out the variable (ignoring the warning) I just get `null`

Comment: How peculiar. I've just tried the code (stripped down to `$GLOBALS[$key] = $value` inside the function), called it and got exactly the desired result...

Comment: Peculiar indeed. I tested my code here https://onlinephp.io/c/04da9 and I too get the desired result, however even if I copy paste this into my file, I still get null. I will have to look further into my setup and not so the code itself...

Comment: I fear that to be true. Maybe you've run into some kind of bug of your PHP version.

Comment: Hm, no, I set the fiddle I linked to use the same version 8.0.25